# Return Array Element inside of an Object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this code below. I want to access the array(named link1 and link2) elements inside of the obj array.

```
$(function() {
    var storage = chrome.storage.local;
    storage.clear();
    var link1 = 'myLinks1';
    var link2 = 'myLinks2';

    var obj= {};

    obj[link1] = ['www.google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'www.msn.com'];
    obj[link2] = ['www.microsoft.com', 'live.com', 'www.espn.com'];

    storage.set(obj);

    storage.get(null,function(result){
        //returns obj with array of links inside
        console.log(result);
        // Returns array of obj but doesn't contain array of links inside.
        console.log(Object.keys(result));
    });
});
```

EDIT: I want to be able to access the links such as www.Google.com

Thanks

Comment: What _does_ the last line output for you? Based on the code I'd expect it to return `["myLinks1","myLinks2"]`

Comment: `console.log(Object.keys(result).reduce(function(arr,k){return arr.concat(result[k])}, []));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the keys and array values in the result by writing the following for loop

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]); 
   for (var i in obj[key]) 
    console.log(obj[key][i]); 
});
```

output:

> myLinks1 ["www.google.com", "yahoo.com", "www.msn.com"]
>   www.google.com
>   yahoo.com
>   www.msn.com
>   myLinks2 ["www.microsoft.com", "live.com", "www.espn.com"]
>   www.microsoft.com
>   live.com
>   www.espn.com